# How I can reload an image on Kivy + Python

Tags: python, image, kivy, reload

I´m using kivy + phyton for develop digital catalog for IOS and Androdi but i don´t know how I can reload image for this case.

On main.py

```
class Pgrid(Screen):
   _ImagenFavorito = str

   def get_ImgFavorito(self, arg):
      img = arg
      for i in range(len(Heart_Array)):
        if Heart_Array[i][0] == img and Heart_Array[i][1] == 0:
            return 'data/icons/black/heart_empty_icon&16.png'
        else:
            if Heart_Array[i][0] == img and Heart_Array[i][1] == 1:
                return 'data/icons/black/heart_icon&16.png'

def update_corazon(self, picid):
    #lg = picid
    for i in range(len(Heart_Array)):
        if Heart_Array[i][0] == picid:
            Heart_Array[i][1] = 1
            return 'data/icons/black/heart_icon&16.png'
pass
```

.kv file

```
<Pgrid>:
   BoxLayout:
      orientation: 'vertical'
      canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .9, .9, .9
       Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            source: 'data/background_lite.png'
    BoxLayout:
        GridLayout:
            rows: 3
            colds: 4
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10, 10

            #GRID 1.1
            GridLayout:
                rows: 2
                clods: 1
                Image:
                    id: pic11
                    source: 'data/products/camabe.jpg'
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint:1, 0.1
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 0
                        Rectangle:
                            size: self.size
                            pos: self.pos
                    ImageButton:
                        id: 11
                        source: root.get_ImgFavorito(11)
                        #size_hint: .2, .2
                        pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.50, 'center_x': 0.50}
                        on_press: root.update_corazon(11)
```

When I run and click over ImageButton call roo.update_corazon(11) and update Heart_Array but I don´t know how reload the source ofo this ImageButton.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

---

On my .py I change to this:

```
 def update_corazon(self, picid):
    for i in range(len(Heart_Array)):
        if Heart_Array[i][0] == picid:
            Heart_Array[i][1] = 1
            self.manager.current = 'pgrid'
```

And now I think self.manager.current = 'pgrid' will be reload Pgrid screen but don´t reload the screen :(

Comment: Finally I change many things like this and all work now:                                                                    
                self.remove_widget(Pgrid(name='pgrid'))
                self.add_widget(Pgrid(name='pgrid'))                                                           and on .kv only -> on_press: root.update_corazon(xx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I change many things like this and all work now:

```
self.remove_widget(Pgrid(name='pgrid')) 
self.add_widget(Pgrid(name='pgrid'))
```

and on .kv only -> `on_press: root.update_corazon(xx)`